# How to change architecture mac os x

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal, cpu-architecture

Hi all I need to change architecture type in the file.

when I do `lipo -info` command I get only arm7 but I need to have i386 next to it.

Is there any command that can add me i386 info inside the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called `cc`, but it depends on some minor configuration files (*.m or *.c files).

**Edit:** Sorry for not making the joke obvious. What I wanted to say is:

There's not way to change the architecture of an executable file. Executables are produced by compiling source code to machine code and this process is not reversible. You'll need the original source code to recompile the project to the missing architecture. Then you can use `lipo` to combine the executables to a fat binary.

Comment: What he's saying (sarcastically) is that you have to build for the i386 architecture in order to have that in your file.